# how to save data to iCloud from coredata in ios

Tags: ios

I have done with the following steps.
Added the "iCloud" entitlement to your App ID
Added the "iCloud containers" entitlement to your App ID
Added the "iCloud" entitlemen to your entitlements file
Link CloudKit.framework

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add more information to this question, including information on where you are having trouble.

Comment: I don't know how to implement please help

Comment: @romie singh, it may help you to search for some examples on the internet